# Import Configurable Product in Magento with all the details in only 1 row per product in CSV file

Tags: configurable-product, csv, simple-product, associated-products

I have five hundred configurable products, all of them having five color options and five size options.
In default importing style of magento, I would have to create 26 rows per product in my CSV import file, one row for configurable product and other 25 (1x5x5=25) for simple products.
And for 500 products, creating 26 rows per product will take forever.

Is there any way, by which I could define both configurable and all its simple products in one row only in csv file, instead of 26 rows per product and be able to import into magento.

OR

Can this task be done like that, I create 500 rows for all 500 configurable products and by some excel formula, all the combinations of simple products for all the 500 configurable products be generated in another excel sheet containing the resulted 12500 rows (500x5x5=12500) of simple products?

OR

Any other way you experts can suggest to solve my problem?

P.S.- In Magmi also, I would have to create 25 rows for simple products manually with one configurable products. So, its also not solving my problem.

Basically, I need automation for creation of simple products rows in CSV Files.

Answer (score 2):

You need one row per simple and one for each configurable

Comment: That is only the problem, as I need automation to create rows for simple products in bulk, either by excel formulas or vb script.

In my example there are 500 products, so creating 12500 simple products rows (5x5x500) is very much cumbersome. That's why I need some quick solution.

Comment: I deal with a large catalog as well and have not found anything that will auto generate. Luckily we use Amazon as a seller portal, so I am able to take their spreadsheet and copy the information to columns in a new spreadsheet, then use Magmi to import. It's tedious, but accurate.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done, as I am in the same boat as you, is made 2 files - one files with all the simple products and one file with all the configurable products. At least this will allow you to better organize yourself and all you need to do is upload both files using the magento product importer and it works.

I am still trying to see how to simplify the configurator product file and reduce the 20 lines I have per product into 1 row.

Comment: Did you find a solution for the 1 ROW OF DATA import?